# Scrollable message box with image iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm making an application in iphone of famous leader so for that I need a message box with image of that leader and brief description of him/her. also it should be scrolled if the description is large.

Comment: Good for you, but http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `UITextView` for your this requirement and set `UIImageView` behind of this `UITextView` Control.

for example see this bellow code..

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 300)];
textView.delegate = self;
textView.text = @"Your Description";
textView.editable = NO;
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIImageView *imgeBack = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image Name"]];
imgeBack.frame = textView.frame;
[self.view addSubview:imgeBack];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: Thanks Paras for the answer and its really helpfull

Comment: Vladimir, C. A. McCann, petert, Kris Erickson, Blazemonger to u all that if u r not able to understand question its doesn't mean the question is vague..

Comment: @user1806581 this answer is right and useful mate??